# aws-iot-device-sdk Thing Shadow disconnecting device

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I have written a code for AWS IoT using 'aws-iot-device-sdk'. I am able to create a device and publish. The device does not disconnect in between. (stand alone)
I am also able to create a shadow device and publish, subscribe correctly (stand alone).

However when I connect the 2, the device keeps getting disconnected and reconnect.

I have searched but unable to find any solution.

Below is the code I have written. Kindly advice what I am doing wrong

**index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

const Constants = require('./constants');
const Transmission = require('./transmission');
const ThingShadow = require('./thingShadow');

execute = () => {
  ThingShadow.shadowing();
  Transmission.transmit();
}

execute();
```

**thingShadow.js**

```
const awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
const Constants = require('./constants');
const utils = require('./utils');

var thingShadows;

shadowing = () => {
    thingShadows = awsIot.thingShadow({
        keyPath: Constants.ACTUAL_KEY_PATH,
        certPath: Constants.ACTUAL_CERT_PATH,
        caPath: Constants.CA_PATH,
        clientId: Constants.THING_NAME,
        host: Constants.HOST
    });

    thingShadows.on('connect', function () {
        thingShadows.register(Constants.THING_NAME);
    });

    thingShadows.on('status',
        function (thingName, stat, clientToken, stateObject) {
            console.log('received ' + stat + ' on ' + thingName + ': ' +
                JSON.stringify(stateObject));
        });

    thingShadows.on('delta',
        function (thingName, stateObject) {
            console.log(`Delta received `);
        });

    thingShadows.on('timeout',
        function (thingName, clientToken) {
            console.log('received timeout ' + ' on ' + operation + ': ' +
                clientToken);
        });
}

module.exports = {
    shadowing
}

// shadowing();
```

**transmission.js**

```
const awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
const Constants = require('./constants');
const utils = require('./utils');

let data = {
    "records":{
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":"value2",
       "key3":"value3"
    }
 };

 let device;
 transmit = () => {
    // create device
    device = awsIot.device({
        keyPath: Constants.ACTUAL_KEY_PATH,
        certPath: Constants.ACTUAL_CERT_PATH,
        caPath: Constants.CA_PATH,
        clientId: Constants.THING_NAME,
        host: Constants.HOST
    });

    device.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('Connected to AWS');
        callPublisher();
    });

    device.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    device.on('message', function (topic, payload) {
        console.log(`Topic : ${topic}`);
        console.log(`Payload : ${payload}`);
        if (topic === `MyTopic`) {
            device.publish(`MyTopic`, JSON.stringify(data));
        } else {
            console.log('Something else');
        }
    });

    device
      .on('close', function() {
         console.log('close');
   });
   device
      .on('reconnect', function() {
         console.log('reconnect');
      });
   device
      .on('offline', function() {
         console.log('offline');
      });
   device
      .on('error', function(error) {
         console.log('error', error);
      });
}

callPublisher = () => {
    data.records.key1 = 10;
    data.records.key2 = 20;
    device.publish(`MyTopic`, JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(`Data sent : ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
}

module.exports = {
    transmit
}
// transmit();
```

Below is the output of the program

```
Connected to AWS
offline
close
reconnect
Data sent : {"records":{"key1":"10","key2":"20","key3":"value3"}}
```

If anyone has a link/code to connect mqtt.js with nodejs kindly share.

Comment: if the device keeps getting disconnected and reconnect , there are 2 possible problems. 1. You may have mistake in a security policy which device certificate bounded. 2. There will be DUPLICATE_CLIENT_ID. Please add your device policy to the question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MehmetaliSaraç. The issue was due to creating the object and the shadow with the same client id. This was causing the Duplicate client id issue causing the disconnection of one of the objects. I have made a singleton object that is used by both the object and the shadow. The issue has been resolved.